# Grab copy model and save to new object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to move some objects from another model into another one.

`quotes.labouritems` gets me the data I want.

This does not work:

```
newitems = quotes.labouritems.dup
new invoice = invoice.labouritems.build(newitems)
```

Why i'm doing this is that I need the data from `labouritems` but do not want to keep the same id, otherwise anytime they get updated by `quote.labourites` will update the records in `invoice.labouritems`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
newitems = quotes.labouritems.clone
```

Based on this test, it should work:

```
class Foo
end

foo = Foo.new
#=> #<Foo:0x00000002694cc0>
bar = foo.clone
#=> #<Foo:0x000000027e1f10>
```

Comment: yeah but how do i assign it to the invoices model

Comment: I'm not an ActiveRecord expert (or Rails for that matter), but perhaps something like (but probably not exactly):

`invoice = Invoice.new(quotes.labouritems.to_h)`

You might have to implement the `to_h` method for you model if it's not there by default. I believe ActiveRecord allows you to create a new method from a hash, if not, you'll probably have to implement an `initialize` method to init from a hash in Invoice as well.

There's probably a simpler "railsy" way of doing this though.